# Unable to checkout in wordpress due to error "hook uses out of date data structures"

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have installed porto theme in wordpress with woocommerce. But, i am trying to checkout , i have found this error "The The "woocommerce_add_order_item_meta" hook uses out of date data structures and function is deprecated since version 3.1.2. Replace with woocommerce_new_order_item." from yesterday.

Please help

Thanks,

Comment: update your woccomerce plugin version

Answer (score 0):

In WC version 3.0.0
we use **woocommerce_add_order_item_meta** hook and add item meta like this

```
wc_add_order_item_meta ( $item_id, $key, $value );
```

But from WC version 3.0.0+
we have to use this hook **woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item** and add order item meta like this

```
$item->add_meta_data($key,$order_val);
```

Comment: **Sorry but this is not correct:** the function `woocommerce_add_order_item_meta()` is deprecated, **BUT NOT the action hook `woocommerce_add_order_item_meta`** that developers still use in last WooCommerce version and **can't be replaced by `woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item`** !